# Passing $id to a controller

Tags: function, symfony, arguments, entity

Im passing the id of an user to a controller. This id is used to fill a field of another Entity so this entity can know where it belongs to. The code of the controller is

```
 public function nuevamedidaAction($id, Request $peticion){

    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

    $medida = new \Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Medida;

    $medida->setHijo($id);



    $form = $this->createForm(new \Goodday\PreditBundle\Form\MedidaType(), $medida);


    $form->handleRequest($peticion);




        if ($form->isValid()) {


            $em->persist($medida);
            $em->flush();
                                        return $this->render('PreditBundle:Default:test2.html.twig');


        }





    return $this->render('PreditBundle:Medida:newmedida.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'error' => $form->getErrors()));
}
```

now the field "hijo" in my entity looks like:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Hijo", inversedBy="medidas", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hijo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
```

protected $hijo;

It returns me the following error

"Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Medida::setHijo() must be an instance of Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Hijo, string given, called in C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Controller\HijoController.php on line 74 and defined in C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Medida.php line 461"

Thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear: `Argument 1 passed to Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Medida::setHijo() must be an instance of Goodday\PreditBundle\Entity\Hijo, string given`

You must pass an Hijo object to the method `setHijo`

```
$hijo = $em->getRepository('GooddayPreditBundle:Hijo')->find($id);
$medida->setHijo($hijo);
```

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard.

Comment: It solved this problem, now it leads to another but step but step. Thanks!